# Set div height to letter size

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML:

```
<div>
  Ag<div class="rect"></div>
</div>
<div>
  Ag<div class="rect"></div>
</div>
```

I want the size of `.rect` to be the size of the largest character box, so it should align with the ascender height (the A in this example) and go down to the descender height (the g in this example).

A possible solution is to set the height of `.rect` to the line height and to write an `&nbsp;` inside it:

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.rect {
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 10rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Ag<div class="rect">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

But I'm dissatisfied with this solution because it requires me to make sure the div height is consistent with the local line height and the additional `&nbsp;` is just noise. Also, setting `.rect` to the line height, isn't strictly what I want because it could be larger or smaller than the actual characters.

Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: you don't really need the `&nbsp;`, you can keep the div empty since you made it inline-block

Comment: But without the `&nbsp;`, the `.rect` will move upwards a bit, then the bottom side of the `.rect` is aligned with the text baseline.

Comment: use vertical-align: bottom; (or top) to fix this

Comment: Nice! That solves the `&nbsp;` problem. Then, only the height problem remains. Thanks! @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flex
for more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.rect {
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  Ag<div class="rect"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a viable solution, although *not exactly* what I hoped. If you make a border around `.wrap`, you'll see that the height of `.rect` is the height of the container, not the height of the character box.

Comment: Ya you are right. Problem comes from font render every font has initial spacing

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work. According to the css spec, setting line height to just a number: The used value is this unitless  multiplied by the element's own font size. The computed value is the same as the specified . In most cases, this is the preferred way to set line-height and avoid unexpected results due to inheritance.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

```html
<head>
<style>
body {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.rect {
  width: 10rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 1;
}

.wrapper{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  Ag<div class="rect">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for this interesting solution. What's the difference between `line-height: 1` and `line-height: 1em`?

Comment: I just tried out this solution and it's a viable solution. But, it's again *not exactly* what I was hoping for. The `&nbsp;` in `.rect` is required to make this work and the height of the `.rect` doesn't cover the descender space (it's bottom border isn't at the height of g). I'll try to fiddle around a bit with this solution later.